# Update variable inside object inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, object

Will try to explain the issue, sorry if it doesn't make sense:
I'm trying to update a variable inside an object while looping.
Trying to target all the parents of class elements to use on scrollmagic plugin.
This is what my code looks like:

```
var childElement = $('.child');
var myparents = [];

    var getParent = function () {
        childElement.each(function() {
            var theParent = $(this).closest('.parent');
            myparents.push(theParent);
        });         
    }();    

    for (var i=0; i<childElement.length; i++) {
        // also using the loop to add animation to every element, 
        // that's why the loop through other elements
        new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            // here is where I would need to access each
            triggerElement: myparents[i],
            triggerHook: 'onEnter'
        })
    }
```

The elements are added successfully to the array, and can use them, but can't access them inside this scrollmagic (object?).
Thanks a lot to anyone for providing assistance.

Comment: Just because you call a method (ScrollMagic.Scene) and pass in an object {triggerElement: thing, triggerHook: thing2} doesn't mean those values will necessarily be available as properties of your object.  That would depend on the scrollmagic API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily use a shorter version of your code that is less prone to errors and way easier to use 'as a self-contained module', since it's not polluting the scope.

```
$('.child').each(function(){
    var $child = $(this),
        $parent = $child.closest('.parent');
    $child.data('scrollMagic',new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: $parent[0],
        triggerHook: 'onEnter'
    });
});
```

whenever you now need access to the scrollMagic object when you know the child, you can just access `$(<childElement>).data('scrollMagic')`

However, if the object itself is available in the `onEnter` hook depends on how the `scrollMagic` plugin is implemented. That has nothing to do with this code.

Comment: Glad to help! if you continue down the path of jQuery/webdev/javascript in general: keep this example in mind of how you can easily create self-contained code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use like this :

```
var childElement = $('.child');
 childElement.each(function() {
    var theParent = $(this).closest('.parent');
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
       triggerElement: theParent,
       triggerHook: 'onEnter'
    });
 });
```

Comment: This was actually my first approach, but unfortunately didn't work

Comment: can you try to pass a parameter inside each(function(passedParamter) ..) and use $(passedParameter).closest instead of $(this) ?